# can defmacro quota parameter in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a string which will evaluate to true or false, can I use macro and pass the string as parameter? I write the following, but the result is string of (= 0 0) instead of true. How to get true result?

```
(def a "(= 0 0)")

(defmacro test [code-string]  code-string)

(test a)
```

update: 
The purpose is replace dynamic SQL. Currently we store code like 'column_a > 1' in database, and then we will get the code, and assemble a sql like

```
select case when column_a>1 then 0 else 1 end as result from table
```

There are many such  code, and I hope to use clojure run in parallel to speed it up. To use clojure I could store '(> row["column_a"] 1)' in database, and then in jdbc looping, call (> row["column_a"] 1) to do my logic, like storing some code section in database and need to run it.

Comment: The string represents a Clojure expression, right? Does it arise in a context where all its references are resolved? I assume that it is somehow generated at run time. How is it generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TaylanUB already said, Clojure provides [eval](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/eval) to evaluate some expression at run-time. However, using eval is frowned upon unless you have very good reasons to use it. It's not clear what you're really intending to do, so it would be helpful to provide a more real world example. If you don't have one, you don't need eval.
Similarly, macros are used to transform code and are not run at run-time, instead the code to which the macro evaluates gets run. The typical approach would be to try to solve a problem with a mere function, only if a macro would buy you something in terms of applicability to a wider range of code, consider turning the code into a macro. *Edit:* take a look at some introduction to macros in Clojure, e.g. this part from [Clojure from the ground up](http://aphyr.com/posts/305-clojure-from-the-ground-up-macros)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot directly use a string as code. Defmacro takes s-expressions not strings. Clojure might have something like `read` which can parse a string and make an s-expression out of it which you might then be able to execute as code via something like `eval`.

There is *usually* no good reason to put code in strings or other data structures which will exist during program execution anyway, try to just work with first-class functions instead. Or mention the precise problem you're trying to solve and people might be able to give better answers. This might be an instance of the [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY%20Problem).

Note: I don't know Clojure, but all of this is pretty Lisp-generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn eval-code [code-string]
  (eval (read-string code-string)))

(eval-code "(= 0 0)")
```

;; you don't need macro here.